# create numeric column in r using vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector of playoff dates here

```
nflplayoffs <- c('2016-01-09','2016-01-09','2016-01-10','2016-01-10','2016-01-16',)
```

I am trying to add in a numeric column to my data.table based on those dates using the below line

```
trx$nflplayoffs <- as.numeric(trx$date==nflplayoffs)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` when there are multiple elements

```
as.integer(trx$date %in% nflplayoffs)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was an in operator but couldn't remember what it was.